# VBS script to update an Excel pivot table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, vbscript, pivot-table

I'm using a VBS script to run from task scheduler.
It run the .xlsm that contain data on sheet1 (a view from SQL) and a sheet2 with a pivot table.

When I run the .xlsm the data from table update (I have a refreshall and calculate VBA)

When I run the VBS the Excel does not update.

Is there anything from the VBS that prevent the Excel file to update correctly or the SQL data sheet does not update and the pivot table update with not updated value from this table?

How to solve this?

Here is my VBS

```vb
Dim ObjExcel, ObjWB
Set ObjExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")

Set ObjWB = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\ENG\Apps\test.xlsm")

ObjWB.Close False
ObjExcel.Quit
Set objFileName = Nothing
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: Is there another part of your code that refreshes the data and calculations?  The code posted looks like it's just opening and closing the file.

Comment: It's a security issue. You need to say what settings you've set in TS. EG `"C:\ENG\Apps\test.xlsm")` may not be accessible depending on settings.

Comment: Yes, I have a .RefreshAll in Excel VBA. In the TS I use cscript to launch the VBS that launch the .XLSM file with macro. I have many other files that work like this but look like with the pivot table and SQL query it does not update (only that file). It is a user security with the SQL that prevent the task scheduler to update the query??

Comment: Right click the file and read who has what permissions.

Comment: Permission are ok. I have other files with same setting and they work with this current setting. I think it due to SQL Studio view... something does not permit the refreshall while file launched by .vbs

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup where my VBScript will open the file and refresh all, including SQL connection and all Pivot Tables, firstly I would add the code `ObjWB.RefreshAll` before you close the opened file, also it seems `ObjWB.Close False` would close the file without saving the changes.

I also had to make sure that the Query connection in Excel had the following setting checked "Refresh this connection on Refresh All":

[image]

Also just to really make sure that everything did get refreshed, I have the following code in the Workbook, where I had to make sure when refreshing that Background Refresh option was set to False:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Status Report").Range("A1").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Application.EnableEvents = False
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

    'Refresh all pivot tables
    For Each pc In ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches
        pc.Refresh
    Next pc

    For Each pt In ThisWorkbook.PivotTables
        pt.Refresh
    Next pt

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Comment: Not working. My other files are updating but they update an ODBC connection. This one use a "view" from Studio SQL. Is there something preventing the data to refresh??

Comment: @DLP I'm unsure, it worked for my "Microsoft Query" data source, which uses a View from the Data Warehouse, it would be difficult to tell without being able to play with the workbook....